# No site accepts my comments. What's wrong?

Tags: comments

I'm not sure if this question should be asked here or not. I'm the owner of a website, and wherever I put comments on other websites, they don't appear. When I comment with another fake email, it appears.

What's wrong here?

PS: Please don't close this question and migrate it to the appropriate site, if this site is not the true place.

Comment: We need more information - what sort of system are you using for comments?

Comment: I just read my favorite articles on different websites, and I put comments on their site. However, my comment doesn't appear there.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear where you are putting the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The odds are you have been identified as a spammer by antispam services like Akismet and your comments are being deleted as a result of it. This means the comments you leave are coming across and/or are spammy in nature.  If you're going to leave comments on other websites do all of us webmasters a favor and make sure you're leaving thoughtful and meaningful comments and don't just comment for the sake of getting backlinks. Nobody benefits when that is done.

Comment: I thought that too and then I checked Akismet's faq and they said that someone marking your comment as spam on one site won't affect you on other sites. The same may not be true of other anti-spam services.

Comment: I'm guessing that the comments are tripping bayesian filters or other spam filters and are being flagged as spam before webmasters even have a chance to see them.

Comment: @John, what makes a comment a spam? I always provide meaningful comments (not just something like 'thanks, that was nice' or these kind of comments). Is that service tracking the email, or the website, or what?

Comment: @John, how can I tell them that I'm not a spammer. I visited the site and there is no reporting mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

There could be any number of reasons. By default Wordpress does not publish comments automatically; the site owner must approve them first, and once your email is approved future comments may show up instantly.

So many site owners may have glossed over your comment, or it could have been marked as spam by Akismet or a similar service. It's also possible your website or the domain of your email is blacklisted if it's been reported before.

Comment: how to know if my website or email is blacklisted? How to tell them that I'm not an spammer?