# How to tell the world that I'm not an spammer?

Tags: spam, comments, spam-prevention, spamming

In [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19239/no-site-accepts-my-comments-whats-wrong), I just found out that my website address has been reported as spam, by services like Akismet. However, I'm not really an spammer. I'm a web developer, and I'm not selling any product to advertise for. I tended to post "thank you" messages, but I'm not gonna send them even more.

How should I inform the world that I'm not an spammer? How to return my name back to white list, instead of being on black list? Honestly, no site accepts my comments (which are truly relevant and link-free and ad-free). This bothers me a lot. I'm just so lost here. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to go to Akismet and request that they remove you from their list. They're usually responsive to this unless they have reason to believe that you aren't being honest with them. A couple of years ago when I ended up on their list (due to someone else's malicious reporting) it only took them a couple of days to fix it and that was over a holiday weekend.

The other or temporary alternative is to post comments using a different email address and no link to your site. Make sure that any comments you leave are relevant to the topic at hand and not just generic "Great Post!" or "Thanks for posting this." type comments that will probably be flagged as spam.